# Check for a directory inside a subdirectory dynamically

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of domains which points to the same directory "public_html" on my host.
There is a .htaccess file in the main folder that locally redirects each domain to a particular folder with the same name as `%{HTTP_HOST}` mod_rewrite variable. (eg: redirect `www.domain.com` to `public_html/www.domain.com/`)

This is the content of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond /%{HTTP_HOST}/#%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^#]+)#\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

I'm having a problem when it comes to the Directory Slash directive.
If I try to access a folder in the domain url without the forward slash like `http://www.domain.com/folder`, the mod_dir applies the DirectorySlash and externally redirects my request to `http://www.domain.com/www.domain.com/folder/`

I tried applying a 301 redirect AFTER the domain directory redirect like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

But for this to work, I would have to be able to check if the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` exists inside the `%{HTTP_HOST}` 'folder'. I even tried the following, for no success:

```
RewriteCond /%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

How can I check, Dynamically, if the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is a directory, which would be inside a directory with the same name as `%{HTTP_HOST}`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you work with `-d` you need to provide an absolute filesystem path. So try this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```